# How high should CPU usage for Magento 2 during development be?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, magento2, cpu-usage, bitnami

I'm currently developing a Magento 2 website on a t2.micro instance. I understand that a t2.micro is inadequate during production because of Magento 2's minimum system requirements of a 2GB memory, but I don't know if the development server should even be running out of CPU credits.

The current baseline CPU usage (based on the Amazon EC2 console) is at *60%* when there are enough credits, and using `top` to investigate, I found the culprit for this to be Magento 2's cron jobs. I also fixed a cron task which was permanently on the `running` state and deleted all old and completed cron jobs in the database, but this did not seem to help significantly.

I did not have this issue before so I'm wondering if this is due to some extensions I've recently installed, namely `Mageplaza SMTP`, `Mageplaza Blog Extension`, and `Mailchimp for Magento 2`. Has anyone faced this problem in development before as well?

Answer (score 2):

Cron jobs, by default, take up a lot of CPU power.

What it does is it runs a lot of cleanup and maintenance stuff in the backend, eating up CPU power.

Aside from that, it runs every minute by default.

What I can suggest is to delay the cron job executions from per minute `(*)` to 5 `(*/5)`, 10 `(*/10)`, 15 `(*/15)`, or maybe 30 minutes `(*/30)`.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! Will try it when I resume that project.